# Asymptotically comparing n⁽¹⁰ ˡᵒᵍ ⁿ⁾ and (log n)ⁿ

Tags: math, big-o, complexity-theory

I've got this problem as home-task in computer science (data structures): find and compare the big-O complexity of the following functions:

- f(n) = n<sup>10 log n</sup>
- g(n) = (log n)<sup>n</sup>

I've tried a number of things like noting that n<sup>10log n</sup> = O(n<sup>n</sup>) and that (log n)<sup>n</sup> = O(n<sup>2</sup>) as well, but that's not helping me here. Any advice about how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It's always easier to compare exponentials if they have the same base. Notice that for any number n we have that

> n = 2<sup>log n</sup>.

From this we get

> n<sup>10 log n</sup> = (2<sup>log n</sup>)<sup>10 log n</sup> = 2<sup>10 log<sup>2</sup> n</sup>

and

> (log n) <sup>n</sup> = (2<sup>log log n</sup>)<sup>n</sup> = 2<sup>n log log n</sup>.

From this we get that n<sup>10 log n</sup> = o((log n)<sup>n</sup>) using little-o notation.

Answer (score 0):

> f(n) = n<sup>10 logn</sup>
>
> g(n) = (logn)<sup>n</sup>

Let's compare the functions:

> n<sup>10 logn</sup> = (logn)<sup>n</sup>

applying log on both sides we will get the below

```
10 logn logn = nlogn
```

we substitute any kind of higher n values to compare them. Let's take 2<sup>128</sup> for easy computation purpose.

> 10 * log 2<sup>128</sup> * log 2<sup>128</sup> = 2<sup>128</sup> * (log 2<sup>128</sup>)
>
> 10 * 128 * 128 = 2<sup>128</sup> * 128

From the above values we could see right side function is higher value - 2<sup>128</sup> * 128.

Hence we can say

```
f(n)=O(g(n))
```